# Looking for a Data Catalog and Data Lineage Tool That Can Integrate With My Snowflake and Informatica Environment

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica, catalog, data-lineage

In my data platform I leverage Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services for orchestrating and processing data into my data warehouse. My data warehouse is in Snowflake. I am looking to start data governance which includes incorporating a data catalog and data lineage tool into my environment. I understand that Informatica has a data cataloguing tool that would work very well but it is too expensive. My question is, is there another Data Catalog/Lineage tool that can be leveraged and will read metadata from the Informatica ETL processes and automatically derive data lineage even though I am not performing push-down queries into my Snowflake data warehouse? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ask your Snowflake sales rep? They know the partnerships well, and can suggest based on your needs. Also try https://reddit.com/r/snowflake